# aws_s3 - not sure if I understand how to use

Tags: ansible

So I wondering if ansible supports s3, from what I see it does but I just might not understand how to do it. Im a novice at Ansible, esp in the realm of using it in conjunction  with AWS.

So I *think* I have to create a role and call it in my playbook?

When I initially tried to add it to a playbook, I got this error:

when I run it, I get this:

```
ERROR! 'aws_s3' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

I created the role and am calling it in my playbook but I get this error.

```
EntePLAY [Test creating ec2 instance with Ansible] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Start New ec2 Instance] ****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ec2) module: roles Supported parameters include: assign_public_ip, aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, count, count_tag, debug_botocore_endpoint_logs, ebs_optimized, ec2_url, exact_count, group, group_id, id, image, instance_ids, instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior, instance_profile_name, instance_tags, instance_type, kernel, key_name, monitoring, network_interfaces, placement_group, private_ip, profile, ramdisk, region, security_token, source_dest_check, spot_launch_group, spot_price, spot_type, spot_wait_timeout, state, tenancy, termination_protection, user_data, validate_certs, volumes, vpc_subnet_id, wait, wait_timeout, zone"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
r code here...
```

Here is my playbook

```
---

- name: Test creating ec2 instance with Ansible
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Start New ec2 Instance
    ec2:
      image: ami-0e8c04af2729ff1bb
      region: us-east-1
      instance_type: t2.micro
      key_name: mykey
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-9983434
      roles:
        - s3
      assign_public_ip: yes
      group:  ansible-test
```

my role might just not be correct too

```
---

- name: Create S3 Bucket
  aws_s3:
    bucket: mybucket-010101
    mode: create
    permission: private-read
    region: us-east-1
```

I just don't know what I am messing up on.

any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Hi..WC to SO! please share your playbook code and the role module of the ec2....The error `Unsupported parameters for (ec2) ` us because of the usage of an unsupported parameter from the list. For this `ERROR! 'aws_s3' is not a valid attribute for a Play` I need to check the role

Comment: hi..so is there a way to update the original post. I tried to add it as a comment but it comes out horrible.

Comment: you can click on edit from the post and then update it

Comment: I have edited it..thanks

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207980/aws-s3-not-sure-if-i-understand-how-to-use

Comment: So I figured it out. In my play I referenced ec2 also. I landed up using the module s3 _bucket because I wanted to add a policy also in my play. Aws_s3 does not appear to support also adding a policy from what I read.

Comment: Yes....if this problem is resolved. please update this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my play I referenced ec2 also. I landed up using the module s3_bucket because I wanted to add a policy also in my play. Aws_s3 does not appear to support also adding a policy from what I read. OTher that that, this was enough to get me to the point I needed to complete my task.